# Cant use let variables in when condition

Tags: common-lisp

I have following code snippet:

```
(defun upsi()
    (let ((firstpos (car *old-list*)) (secondpos (car(cdr *old-list*))))
        (let ((found nil)(secondlocation (list (car (cdr firstpos)) (car secondpos))))
            (when (= (found nil))
                (setq *new-list* (list(firstlocation)))))))
```

This gives me following error `"The function COMMON-LISP-USER::FOUND is undefined"`
But when I try this code, it works perfectly.

```
(defun upsi()
    (let ((firstpos (car *stenches*)) (secondpos (car(cdr *stenches*))))
        (let ((found nil)(secondlocation (list (car (cdr firstpos)) (car secondpos))))
            (print found)
            (print secondlocation))))
```

What is the cause, that I cant use the variables `found` and `secondlocation` in my `when` condition. In fact I also cant use them in a loop. But when I print them I dont get any errors. It looks to me that they are out of scope but I dont understand why ?

I am just into common-lisp but this confuses me so much^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses carry semantic meaning in Common Lisp, and you can't just place them anyplace you like as you can in many other languages. The first position of a list expression is interpreted as an identifier for a function, and that function is called on the arguments; this will fail when there is no such function.

In `(when (= (found nil))` you are calling the function `found`, which doesn't exist. You probably meant `(when (= found nil))`, but this wouldn't work either because [`=` is meant for comparing numbers in Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#EQ). You could use the [`null`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_null.htm) predicate, or it might be better to use an [`unless`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_when_.htm) form instead of `when`.

The same problem also seems to occur in the body of the `when` form: `(list (firstlocation))`. Here the parentheses indicate that `firstlocation` is a function that you want to call. I don't think that this is the case given that `secondlocation` is a list, but I don't see `firstlocation` defined anyplace so I could be wrong.

A couple of other observations: there is a [`let*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) form that allows you to use identifiers which were previously bound in the same form. There is also `cadr` to use instead of calling `car` on the result of calling `cdr`, or you could use `second`. As presented here, your code is very difficult to read and reason about; you should really use an editor that properly indents your code, and look at some examples of lisp written by experienced programmers to get a feel for what it should look like.

Here are a couple of rewritten versions of your code; the first uses `null` and the second uses `unless`. I have assumed that `firstlocation` is a list, and just renamed `secondlocation` to `firstlocation` since `secondlocation` isn't used in the posted code for the sake of getting the code to function.

```lisp
(defvar *old-list* '())
(defvar *new-list* '())

;; Using `let*`, `cadr`, and `when` with `null`:

(defun upsi()
  (let* ((firstpos (car *old-list*))
         (secondpos (car (cdr *old-list*)))  ; could also use `cadr` or `second`
         (found nil)
         (firstlocation (list (cadr firstpos) (car secondpos))))
    (when (null found)
      (setq *new-list* (list firstlocation)))))
```

```lisp
;; Using `let*`, `second`, and `unless`:

(defun upsi()
  (let* ((firstpos (car *old-list*))
         (secondpos (car (cdr *old-list*)))  ; could also use `cadr` or `second`
         (found nil)
         (firstlocation (list (second firstpos) (car secondpos))))
    (unless found
      (setq *new-list* (list firstlocation)))))
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the information. I see, I have some more research to do for common lisp. To be honest, to me the syntax looks so complicated and simple at the same time which leads to so much confusion.  

Nevertheless, thank you very much!